# How keep column names when merge/concat in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

i have a dataframe created in pandas which is looks like this:

```
        A           B           C       
        X   Y   Z   X   Y   Z   X   Y   Z
Y   K   2   5   12  11  9   8   4   5   12
    K   4   4   13  15  5   4   6   7   2
    K   6   7   14  0   2   3   0   6   8
C   M   4   5   12  5   2   2   1   14  0
    M   6   7   2   3   1   6   7   12  5
    M   0   6   8   7   3   9   6   8   4
D   N   7   1   13  15  9   8   1   13  5
    N   9   0   14  0   5   4   0   14  6
    N   3   2   12  5   2   3   1   2   2
```

I want to make it looks like this:

```
        A           B           C       
        X   Y   Z   X   Y   Z   X   Y   Z
Y   K   2   5   12  11  9   8   4   5   12
    K   4   4   13  15  5   4   6   7   2
    K   6   7   14  0   2   3   0   6   8
        A           B           C       
        X   Y   Z   X   Y   Z   X   Y   Z
C   M   4   5   12  5   2   2   1   14  0
    M   6   7   2   3   1   6   7   12  5
    M   0   6   8   7   3   9   6   8   4
        A           B           C       
        X   Y   Z   X   Y   Z   X   Y   Z
D   N   7   1   13  15  9   8   1   13  5
    N   9   0   14  0   5   4   0   14  6
    N   3   2   12  5   2   3   1   2   2
```

Is there is any way i can do that? I have tried several ways with concat/merge/join, but i didn't find a way how i can keep column names for "Y,C,D"

Comment: The structure in your desired output is not exactly a dataframe structure

Comment: Out of curiousity, why would you want your dataframe like this? Or is your question: "how to export a pandas dataframe to excel in the following format?"

Comment: I need to export it to google sheet in this format

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible using the standard DataFrame string output/display functions.  If there were a way to do that it might be a "display option" but those are all listed here and I don't see a relevant one for you: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options

Comment: may be there is another way? Like create separate data frames from Y,C,D 
I want to export data in google sheet in this format.

Comment: Sure, you can create separate DataFrames and print them one after the other.